# Untitleded.sol:5:77: ParserError: Expected type name function sendmessage(string message) view public returns(string message, memory) { ^----^(i need)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, error

I've seen the other StackExchange errors but it didn't help me.

> Untitleded.sol:5:77: ParserError: Expected type name function sendmessage(string message) view public returns(string message, memory) { ^----^

This is the full code:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract chat{
   event sendmessage(string message);
   function sendmessage(string message) view public returns(string message, memory) {
       emit sendmessage(message);
       return message;
   }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. The fixed code block is below.

1. You need to use `memory` or `calldata` when declaring strings
2. Your event name and your function name cannot match
3. Since you are `emit`ting an event, you need to remove the `view` modifier
4. The syntax of your `returns` statement is incorrect
5. (Styling) The name of the contract should be PascalCase (e.g., `Chat`)
6. (Styling) The name of your event should be PascalCase (e.g., `SendMessage`)

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract chat{
   event SendMessage(string message);
   
   function sendmessage(string memory message) public returns(string memory) {
       emit SendMessage(message);
       return message;
   }
}
```